# Extracting mySQL query result from PHP object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, arrayobject

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to get on of them to work for me. The PHP script passes database results to JavaScript like this:

```
$queryResult =  mysqli_query($dbase, $query);

if ($queryResult) {
  $result = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) {
      $result[] = $row;
  }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

JavaScript then receives this through AJAX *(result of console.log)*:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Babe Ruth","loginID":"babe","loginPW":"babe123"}]
```

I've tried *JSON.stringify*, *Object.keys(arr)*, *foreach ($arr as $key => $value)*, *for(i in arr)*, but all to no success.

How can I read this as key-value pairs?

TIA.

Comment: try Json.parse() as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: Thanks ju. Apparently that was the right method, although it had to be accessed with id keys, as Vasya had indicated *(the marked answer)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You response is array of objects, You can use next code:

```
var users = JSON.parse(response);

for(var objId in users) {
    // here you can use construction users[objId].your_key

    console.log('id', users[objId].id);
    console.log('name', users[objId].name);
    console.log('loginID', users[objId].loginID);        
    console.log('loginPW', users[objId].loginPW);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Vasya Zhuryk! It worked perfectly, finally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `JSON.parse`, e.g

```
var user = JSON.parse(response)[0];

// Should print "Babe Ruth"
console.log(user.name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it just returned *undefined*.

Comment: I tried your original posted code, but must have missed your edit. *This works too.* Thank you, J0sh0nat0r.

Answer (score 1):

What you've copied looks like a JS array containing one object.

Assuming your array is `arr` then:

```
var obj = arr[0];

console.log(obj.id);
```

If what you pasted was actually a string, then you'll need to parse that JSON string with `var arr = JSON.parse(response);` and continue as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it just returned *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the index `0` of your response, then you can manipulate your object.

```
var response = [{"id":"1","name":"Babe Ruth","loginID":"babe","loginPW":"babe123"}];
response = response[0];

console.log(response.id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it just returned *undefined*.